# how to save HREF url as a parameter

Tags: javascript

i have a page
http://www.1refer.com/results.php?q=emirates&network=cj
with a script that rewrites the href URL turning it into an affiliate link.
there is also Google Analytics outbound click tracking.
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en
i would like to first capture the rewritten URL as a parameter for GA to use in its redirect to instead of the original URL

Comment: Can you post the script you used to set up the GA outbound tracking?

Comment: var trackOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {'hitCallback':
     function () {
     document.location = url;
     }
   });
}
</script>


and this is the script that rewrites the url
**onclick version**
<script src="//www.anrdoezrs.net/am/7825092/impressions/page/am.js"></script>
**onpageload version**
<script src="//www.anrdoezrs.net/am/7689296/include/allCj/generate/onLoad/impressions/page/am.js"></script> @sam